# ionic cordova speech recognition plugin works well on android but fails on ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition, xcode8

I have created ionic app and used cordova-plugin-speechrecognition for speech to text conversion.

The Code used in the apps is as follows:

```
              initSpeech() {
    this.speechRecognition.hasPermission()
      .then((hasPermission: boolean) => {
        console.log(hasPermission)
        if (!hasPermission) {
          this.speechRecognition.requestPermission()
            .then(
              () => console.log('granted'),
              () => console.log('Denied')
            )
        }
      })
          }

     start() {
  // Start the recognition process
this.speechRecognition.startListening()
  .subscribe(
   (matches: Array<string>) => { this.voicetext = matches[0];         this.mainForm.controls['comments'].setValue(matches[0]); },
(onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
 )
 }

 //stop listening for(ios only)
  stop() {
this.speechRecognition.stopListening();

 }
```

This code runs well on android where the google speech Api gets called.
When I ran it on iOS , I made the required changes like adding 
 NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription permission in info.plist of ios .

Not sure but speech recognition doesn't work on ios 13.3 when I am testing it through the apple developer account test flight app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had any luck with ios? i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, "speechRecognition" only works on the web. I tried to run it on mobile for 2-3 days, but it didn't work.**

[image]